# Jackson annotation not workng

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've been trying to use Jackson annotations to avoid cyclic association but it doesn't seem to work as expected and I still get a stackoverflow

`Allergens` class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;


/**
 * The persistent class for the allergens database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="allergens")
@NamedQuery(name="Allergen.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM Allergen a")
//@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")

public class Allergen{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int id;

    private boolean isEnabled;

    private String title;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Recipe
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Recipe recipe;

    //+getters/setters
```

`Recipe` Class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * The persistent class for the recipes database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="recipes")
@NamedQuery(name="Recipe.findAll", query="SELECT r FROM Recipe r")
//@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class Recipe{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int id;

    private String complexity;

    private int cookingTime;

    private String description;

    private int estimatedTime;

    private String imageUrl;

    private String information;

    private boolean isPromoted;

    private int preparationTime;

    private float servings;

    private String title;

    private String type;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Allergen
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="recipe")
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Allergen> allergens;

//+getters/setters
```

I've also tried annotating both classes with `@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")` but that also didn't work unfortunately

Is there anything I'm missing?

Also, my `pom.xml` contains

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Do I need anything else for jackson?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add [`@JsonIgnore`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) on the property that is causing the circular reference. This will tell Jackson not to serialize that property.

Comment: I tried using `@JsonIgnore` from `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore` for the Recipe object in `Allergens` class and ditch the `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference` but I still get Stackoverflow exception

Comment: So maybe the problem is not about Jackson but about your JPA mapping ?

Comment: I don't know, doubt it, it looks fine to me. I get this error when I'm trying to use the GET method from a rest service. On JBoss I could see the infinite cycling in the json but on glassfish i get straight up stackoverflow exception.

Also, the model was created automatically by some JPA tool in eclipse

Comment: I would try to debug and add a breakpoint after fetching your entity to see if it looks find before serializing. Also I would recommend to not return directly your entity but a `DTO` which is a not managed object containing your data.